# How To add this tag <div class="sub-menu"> before drop-down ul. in wordpress

Tags: menus

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="hover_slip">
                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="arrow_down"><a href="about.html">About Us</a>
                            <div class="sub-menu">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="advisor.html">Advisor</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="single-advisor.html">Single Advisor</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="career.html">Career</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="testimonial.html">Testimonaials</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="partners.html">partners</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="arrow_down"><a href="service.html">Services</a>
                            <div class="sub-menu">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="service2.html">Service Two</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="pricing-page.html">Pricing Page</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
```

Comment: looks like it's already there.

Answer (score 0):

Sense you want to customize the flow of how menus are built OOTB, I highly recommend studying on up the built in method  wp_get_nav_menu_items().  By seeing and manipulating menu lists as seperate objects, you could construct the HTML around the data however you desire to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery wrap function to do this. below code will help you to do this.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="hover_slip">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class="arrow_down"><a href="about.html">About Us</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="advisor.html">Advisor</a></li>
            <li><a href="single-advisor.html">Single Advisor</a></li>
            <li><a href="career.html">Career</a></li>
            <li><a href="testimonial.html">Testimonaials</a></li>
            <li><a href="partners.html">partners</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="arrow_down"><a href="service.html">Services</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="service2.html">Service Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="pricing-page.html">Pricing Page</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>   

<script>
    jQuery(function($){
       $('#hover_slip > li > ul').wrap("<div class='sub-menu'></div>");
    });
</script>
```